# change input number by user input not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Right now I have an input field:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="distance"></input>
```

In the JS I assign the distance to a value:

```
$scope.distance = 0;
```

I want this value to change when the user enters in a value and clicks a button. I have the button setup with my controller... But every time the button is clicked, it displays the value as 0.

Function when button is clicked:

```
//convert button function for when button is clicked
$scope.convert = function(myUnit, myUnit2, distance){
    alert(distance);
}
```

The button:

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="convert(myUnit.thisunit, myUnit2.thisunit2, {{distance}})">
    Convert
</button>
```

Comment: added the function and button

Comment: Use `convert(myUnit.thisunit, myUnit2.thisunit2, distance)`. You're already in an AngularJS expression, no need to add the braces `{{…}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change ng-click to this `ng-click="convert(myUnit.thisunit, myUnit2.thisunit2,  distance)"` because you were using `{{distance}}` interpolation directive inside `ng-click` directive that will never pass distance value

**HTML**

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="convert(myUnit.thisunit, myUnit2.thisunit2, distance)">
    Convert
</button>
```

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the structure of your HTML, (if you have an `ngIf` above your `<input>`) the *distance* model may not be trickling up to your controller.

You should probably nest it for safety, like so:

```
$scope.formData = {distance: 0};
```

And then:

```
<input type="number" ng-model="formData.distance"></input>
```

Also, your click-handler should just read from the `$scope` value as well:

```
$scope.clickHandler = function() {
    alert(formData.distance);
}
```